# How do I fix "Cannot read property 'router' of undefined" error in React Native

Tags: react-native, error-handling

[The image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiBX2.png)

This is all in React Native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code place the below line in your App.js

```
AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

instead of

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer();
```

Comment: I still need the const for it to be perfectly fine, but other than that it worked, :)

Comment: Thats ok you can add the const and get it run as per the requirement no issue in doing so. You can add it this way const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator); The only issue was with not having AppNavigator passed